# Extract Json data from a spark dataframe

Tags: python, json, dataframe, pyspark, databricks

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| message                                                          |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"name":"east-desktop","viewers":447,"emptyCount":0,"version":0.3}|
|{"name":"west-desktop","viewers":111,"emptyCount":0,"version":0.6}|
|{"name":"west-desktop","viewers":115,"emptyCount":0,"version":0.1}|
+------------------------------------------------------------------+

message:string
```

I have a dataframe which contains json data within one column, I would like to extract the data in to either separate columns or as json file.

I am working within a Databricks notebook using pyspark.

Dataframe

```
+---------------------------------------------+
| name        | viewers| emptyCount | version |
+---------------------------------------------+
|east-desktop | 447    | 0          | 0.3     |
|west-desktop | 111    | 0          | 0.6     |
|west-desktop | 115    | 0          | 0.1     |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

OR Json

```
{
  "name": "east-desktop",
  "viewers":  447,
  "emptyCount": 0,
  "version": 0.3,
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pault was right it is pretty much the same question, but you can use the following sample to achieve your dataframe output:

```
df_new = spark.createDataFrame([
(str({"name":"east-desktop","viewers":447,"emptyCount":0,"version":0.3}))
],StringType())

schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField('name', StringType(), True),
        StructField('viewers', IntegerType(), True),
        StructField('emptyCount', IntegerType(), True),
        StructField('version', FloatType(), True)
   ]
)
df_new.withColumn("data", from_json("value",schema)).select("value", col('data.*')).show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+-------+----------+-------+
|value                                                                    |name        |viewers|emptyCount|version|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+-------+----------+-------+
|{'emptyCount': 0, 'version': 0.3, 'name': 'east-desktop', 'viewers': 447}|east-desktop|447    |0         |0.3    |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+-------+----------+-------+
```